# Hexagonal Kurokuron

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Kurokuron (クロクロ一ン: "black clone"), is a shading puzzle that first appeared in Puzzle Communication Nikoli issues 153-155. Identical rules apply to a hexagonal grid.

## Rules

Shade some cells such that:

1. Bold-outlined regions contain exactly two shapes, made up of
   contiguous groups of 1 or more shaded cells. Within a region, the
   two shapes must be congruent, allowing reflection and rotation.
2. A shape cannot share an edge with another shape.
3. Cells with arrows,
   which cannot be shaded, point to a neighboring cell, which must be
   shaded and part of a shape consisting of the given number of cells.

## Example

[image: Example]

[image: Example Solution]

## Puzzle

[image: PSE Hexagonal Kurokuron]

Comment: Can two arrows point to the same thing?

Comment: @boboquack yes, that is possible

Comment: I'd like to thank you for introducing me to a new kind of puzzle! This is like  some combination of two of my favorite puzzle types: sudoku and picross!

Comment: @feelinferrety I hope we see more of this kind of puzzle.  They're so much fun to make.  I'd say it's more similar to Kurotto.

Comment: @paramesis I hadn't heard of that one either. :3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Final grid

(red is shaded, gray is not shaded)

> [image]

### Explanation (Potential spoilers!)

Note that there really is one possibility to fit two regions into the 4 region (all other ways to put two 4-shapes cause them to touch). The same applies to the 6 region in the upper left corner:

[image]

From here, I figured out that if the puzzle were to have a unique solution, then the two shapes in the 2 region had to not touch other regions as much as possible, leading to this:

[image]

From here there is only one way to fill the central 7 region, and the 6 region follows easily.

[image]

Comment: Just beat me...

Comment: Yeah, unique solution method was easiest

Comment: I'm not crazy about uniqueness as a solving method.  I'm glad it didn't replace critical parts of the solve path.